# How to create dynamic, multiple partial views using repository pattern in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, model, partial-views, renderpartial

I am trying to have a general home page that depending on the parameter passed to the control, different content (modules) will be displayed.

For example, a user may select Kentucky from the menu and the id for Kentucky is 1.  The home controller gets the id (1) and determines the possible modules for that
state (a simple db call.)  Perhaps there is an announcements module and a contacts module for the state.  An announcements module could have several items but it's only one module.  There would be a partial view for each type of module.

Here is the basic setup I have.

```
public interface IModuleRepository
{
    IList<MenuItemModule> GetMenuItemModules(int menuItem);
    IList<Announcements> GetAnnouncements(int modID);
    IList<News> GetNews(int modID);
    IList<Contacts> GetContacts(int modID);
}



//business object
public class MenuItemModule
{

    private int _MenuItemID;
    private int _ModuleID;
    private int _ModuleDefID;
    private string _Src;
    private int _ModuleOrder;

//get, set properties for these...

}

//announcements entity
public class Announcements
{
    private int _ID = -1;
    private int _MenuItemID = -1;
    private int _ModuleID = -1;
    private string _Description = string.Empty;

//get set props ...
}
```

In my home controller...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    private IModuleRepository modRepository;

    public HomeController(IModuleRepository modRepository)
    {
        this.modRepository = modRepository;
    }


    public ViewResult Item(string ItemID)
    {

        //returns a list of menuitemmodules for the page.  This gives me the Src or name of each
        //module on the page, i.e. Announcements, news, contacts, etc. 
        var modules = modRepository.GetMenuItemModules(Convert.ToInt32(ItemID)); 


        return View(modules);

   }

}
```

I have tried several different models to return but I always run up against some contstraint.  If I pass the menuitemmodules to my Item.aspx, then I can do something like this:

```
   foreach (var mod in Model)           
   {               
        Html.RenderPartial(mod.Src, a);      //needs an announcement object though    
   }
```

That makes it somewhat dynamic because I have the Src which would basically be something like "Announcements" and I can just create an announcements.ascx partial to process the module.  But I have found it difficult to pass my menuitemmodule and an announcements entity as well.

I have also messed around with passing a more complex object and then testing every Src that comes through with an If statement.  This would make scaling difficult in the future as I increase the number of possible modules in the app.

How can I solve my problem?  I hope I have provided enough info.  I like the basic idea here - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels but that seems to only work for static modules on a page.

I did try a composite view model called ModuleViewModel.  Here is that attempt:

```
public class ModuleViewModel
{
    public IList<Announcements> announcements { get; set; }
    public IList<MenuItemModule> mods { get; set; }

}
```

If I pass that model to the Item.aspx I can do something like this (but I must be doing something wrong because something doesn't look right.)

```
   foreach (var mod in Model)           
   {

       if (mod.announcements.Count > 0)
       {
           Html.RenderPartial("Announcements", mod.announcements);
       }


   }
```

Once again, scalability is going to haunt me.  I would like to have something like this on item page:

```
   foreach (var mod in Model)           
   {

           Html.RenderPartial(mod.Src, mod);          

   }
```

That would the correct partial view and pass it the correct model.

Comment: Have you tried using `Html.DisplayFor(...)`?  It will render the DisplayTemplate that matches the property's type.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  How does it know which module type to use?

Comment: Instead of passing Ids or strings you would create a complex view model that includes all of the view models for the different modules on the page and then iterate over them calling DisplayFor to render the appropriate partial view for that `Type` of object.

Comment: That sounds like something I tried.  I created a composite view model called ModuleViewModel.  I'll edit the question and post my attempt at the bottom.  Maybe you can tell me where I went wrong on that approach, because it does seem like that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this for over a week, I finally managed to figure out how MVC can do what I want dynamically.  I decided to post my solution for others that are new to MVC.  Hopefully, the following will clear up the misunderstandings I had (although, at this point in my understanding of MVC, I cannot say this is the best approach.)

I will include the previous code snips and modifications for clarity:

```
 public interface IModuleRepository
 {
      IList<MenuItemModule> GetMenuItemModules(int menuItem);
      IList<Announcements> GetAnnouncements(int modID);
      IList<News> GetNews(int modID);
      IList<Contacts> GetContacts(int modID);
 }



//business object
public class MenuItemModule
{

    private int _MenuItemID;
    private int _ModuleID;
    private int _ModuleDefID;
    private string _Src;
    private int _ModuleOrder;

//get, set properties for these...

}

//announcements entity
public class Announcements  : MenuItemModule
{
    private int _ID = -1;
    private string _Description = string.Empty;

//get set props ...
}
```

I also added another class:

```
public class AnnouncementModule : MenuItemModule
{
    private IList<Announcements> _Announcements;
    //get set prop
}
```

...and I created a model for the view

```
public class HomeItemViewModel
{
    public MenuItemModule[] MenuItemModules { get; set; } //collection of menuitemmodules
}
```

In my home controller...

```
    var menuItemModules = modRepository.GetMenuItemModules(ItemID);

    if (menuItemModules.Count > 0)
    {
        AnnouncementModule aMod;
        MenuItemModule[] mods = new MenuItemModule[menuItemModules.Count()];

        int i = 0;

        //loop through each MenuItemModule assign to the appropriate model
        foreach (MenuItemModule mod in menuItemModules)
        {
            if (mod.Src == "Announcements")
            {
                aMod = new AnnouncementModule();
                aMod.Announcements = modRepository.GetAnnouncements(mod.ModuleID);

                //now add this to the menuitemmodule collection
                mods[i] = aMod;
            }

            if (mod.Src == "Contacts")
            {
                //...
            }

            i++;
        }

    }


    var viewModel = new HomeItemViewModel
    {
        MenuItemModules = mods
    };

    return View(viewModel);
```

Then I used the suggestion to use DisplayFor in the view.  The view is strongly typed to HomeItemViewModel.

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MenuItemModules) %>
```

This iterates through the collection and based on the type, it will call that template.  In this example, it calls AnnouncementModule.ascx which is strongly typed to AnnouncementModule.

```
foreach (var a in Model.Announcements)
{
    //a.Description will give us the description of the announcement
}
```

---

I realize there are slicker ways to code the controller, and I plan on refactoring, but this skeleton should provide the basics to solve the question I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Create Module classes that derive from a common Module base class:

```
public class AnnouncementsModule : Module
{
}

public class ContactsModule : Module
{
}
```

In controller:

Create your various modules and put them into your overall view module (here it has a property called Modules that is an array of `Module`:

```
var viewModel = new ComplexViewModel 
                { 
                    Modules = new [] 
                    { 
                       new ContactsModule(), 
                       new AnnouncementsModule() 
                    }
                 };
return View(viewModule);
```

In view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Modules);
```

Create the partial views for each `Type` of Module in the appropriate 'Shared` folder.  (Run it without creating them and it will show you an exception with the locations where it's looking for them).

Comment: Let me try that.  It looks very similar to my first attempt, but I did not create a Module base class. I think that may have been the key.

Comment: Quick question.  What does the array look like in the ComplexViewModel?  Is it just a simple public Module[] Modules {get; set;} ?

Comment: I'm having a mental block on this.  I did that, but I don't have the option to put in new AnnouncementsModule(), etc.  So far I have the public Module[] defined in my complex view model and a public Announcements AnnouncementsModule {get;set;}.  The Announcements class does indeed inherit from the base Module.  What obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: I am probably getting "Create your various modules and put them into your overall view module" wrong.  I assumed this meant putting a reference to each module in the complexviewmodel, i.e. public Announcements AnnouncementModule { get; set; }.  I think this is where I am lost.

Comment: Just for clarification, I followed the above exactly as it is written, but when I got to my view and typed Html.DisplayFor(module); I got this error in design time: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  Hopefully, this will help.  I'm confused in general though.  How would passing an instance of a ContactsModule in the array, display the data in the partial?

Comment: @rahkim - This seems like an awfully ambitious project for you if you are so green don't understand the basics of polymorphism and expressions.  We can help you, but at some point you need to learn and not just copy.  `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Modules)` (take out the for loop, DisplayFor automatically iterates over collections).  I suggest reading here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: @MystereMan - Thanks for the advice.  I've actually read that link before and it is very helpful.  I only decided to copy the code above exactly because everything else I tried (including your suggestion) didn't work.  I figured I must be missing some MVC nuance.  I am familiar with polymorphism but the expressions thing is new to me and so is MVC.  For example, how (in the code above) does adding "new ContactsModule()" to the collection give the view the needed data?

Comment: @rahkim - If you had read the entire link (all parts of it) then you would understand how templates are chosen based on their type.  MVC looks at the collection of modules, and examines each one and calls GetType() on them, then it looks for a template in the templates path of the same name with a .cshtml, .vbhtml, .aspx, or .ascx extension.

Comment: @MystereMan - I completely understand that part of it.  But maybe I need to reread again because I don't understand how "new ContactsModule()" contains the data needed for the template.  My disconnect is between the data call in the conroller and the chosen templates display of that data.

Comment: @rahkim - new ContactsModule() creates a new instance of a class you create called ContactsModule, that is derived from your Module base class.  You place whatever data your contacts module needs in ContactsModule.  In your template, you strongly type it to ContactsModule and then you can access that data.  I don't really understand what problem you're having in understanding this.

Comment: @rahkim - Oh, I think I understand.  It's a typo in the code above.  Either change it to new Contacts() or change the class from Contacts to ContactsModule.

Comment: Here lies my misunderstanding.  "You place whatever data your contacts module needs in ContactsModule."  I did create an instance of ContactsModule and I did fill it with a contact.  But if I put a new instance of ContactsModule in the viewModel passed to the page, I'm not sure how the page has the appropriate data.  It seems like it would have a Module array with an empty ContactsModule class and its data properties.  That's what seems to happen.  My view hits this line - @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Modules); and continues without any error...and without loading the contactsmodule.ascx.